# Get ipad writable directory in Flex

Tags: ios, apache-flex

I am developing an ipad app using Flex (Adobe Air, Flash Builder). 
I understand that in objective-C, you can get the writable directory using NSDocumentDirectory, but how do you do the same in Flex??

In Flex, I use File.applicationStorageDirectory, and it works only when I run in the simulator. If I install the app on my ipad, it doesn't give any error, but I don't think it works.
Please help!!

Answer (score 3):

I would have guessed File.applicationStorageDirectory.  In fact, I have successfully used that to create an SQLLite database on iOS.  I'm not sure why it wouldn't be working.

You may try [File.userDirectory](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#userDirectory).

Comment: +1 for the applicationStorageDirectory! Works 100% without the need to alter any permissions or stuff like that. I've used it several times on both Android and iOS.

Comment: Thank you. It turned out my problem wasn't the storage directory. It turns out that after I write the file to the directory (with no error as mentioned above). I couldn't load it using URLLoader.   var myTextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);          This works perfectly when I run in the simulator. But when I debug it on the device or deploy it, it never got loaded (never went to "onLoaded" function). Do you have anhy suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: You can load the data in the file using the FileStream class and the reference to the File Object:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html If you perform a Google search, there should be plenty of documentation on this.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. I found this post here with similar issue, but there was no anser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352288/urlrequest-and-urlrequest-work-in-simulator-but-not-on-device-flex-mobile